# Spring JPA : How to get Parent Child as nested objects in Many To Many relationship

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, many-to-many

**Requirement:**
How to get all Book objects who contains Publisher > Name contains "Pub2","Pub3" in publisher object.

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "book_id": "1",
            "publishers": [
                {
                    "pub_id": "1",
                    "name": "pub1",
                    "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
                },
                {
                    "pub_id": "2",
                    "name": "pub2",
                    "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "book_id": "2",
            "publishers": [
                {
                    "pub_id": "1",
                    "name": "Pub1",
                    "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
                },
                {
                    "pub_id": "2",
                    "name": "pub2",
                    "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "book_id": "3",
            "publishers": [
                {
                    "pub_id": "3",
                    "name": "Pub3",
                    "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"    
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Relationship Used:**
ManytoMany with Extra Column added in Third Table which contains @EmbeddedId

**Entity Objects:**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Book {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
  private Set<BookPublisher> bookPublishers = new HashSet<>();

  public Book(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}


@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Publisher {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "publisher")
  private Set<BookPublisher> bookPublishers = new HashSet<>();

  public Publisher(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_publisher")
public class BookPublisher {

  @EmbeddedId
  private BookPublisherId id;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("bookId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
  private Book book;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("publisherId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
  private Publisher publisher;

  @Column(name = "published_date")
  private Date publishedDate;

  public BookPublisher(Book book, Publisher publisher, Date publishedDate) {
    this.id = new BookPublisherId(book.getId(), publisher.getId());
    this.book = book;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
  }
}



@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class BookPublisherId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "book_id")
  private Integer bookId;

  @Column(name = "publisher_id")
  private Integer publisherId;

}
```

**Solutions tried so far:**
**Solution: 1**

```
public interface BookPublisherRepository extends JpaRepository<BookPublisher, BookPublisherId> {

  List<BookPublisher> findAllBookByPublisher_NameIn(List<String> s);
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
[
  {
    "id": {
      "bookId": 1,
      "publisherId": 2
    },
    "book": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Book1",
      "bookPublishers": [
        {
          "id": {
            "bookId": 1,
            "publisherId": 2
          },
          "book": 1,
          "publisher": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Pub2",
            "bookPublishers": [
              {
                "id": {
                  "bookId": 1,
                  "publisherId": 2
                },
                "book": 1,
                "publisher": 2,
                "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
              },
              {
                "id": {
                  "bookId": 2,
                  "publisherId": 2
                },
                "book": {
                  "id": 2,
                  "name": "Book2",
                  "bookPublishers": [
                    {
                      "id": {
                        "bookId": 2,
                        "publisherId": 1
                      },
                      "book": 2,
                      "publisher": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Pub1",
                        "bookPublishers": [
                          {
                            "id": {
                              "bookId": 2,
                              "publisherId": 1
                            },
                            "book": 2,
                            "publisher": 1,
                            "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
                          },
                          {
                            "id": {
                              "bookId": 1,
                              "publisherId": 1
                            },
                            "book": 1,
                            "publisher": 1,
                            "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": {
                        "bookId": 2,
                        "publisherId": 2
                      },
                      "book": 2,
                      "publisher": 2,
                      "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "publisher": 2,
                "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
              }
            ]
          },
          "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
        },
        {
          "id": {
            "bookId": 1,
            "publisherId": 1
          },
          "book": 1,
          "publisher": 1,
          "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
        }
      ]
    },
    "publisher": 2,
    "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": {
      "bookId": 2,
      "publisherId": 2
    },
    "book": 2,
    "publisher": 2,
    "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": {
      "bookId": 3,
      "publisherId": 3
    },
    "book": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Book3",
      "bookPublishers": [
        {
          "id": {
            "bookId": 3,
            "publisherId": 3
          },
          "book": 3,
          "publisher": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Pub3",
            "bookPublishers": [
              {
                "id": {
                  "bookId": 3,
                  "publisherId": 3
                },
                "book": 3,
                "publisher": 3,
                "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
              }
            ]
          },
          "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
        }
      ]
    },
    "publisher": 3,
    "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
  }
]
```

**Actual Data:**

```
select * from book;
select * from publisher;
select * from book_publisher;

id  name
1   Book1
2   Book2
3   Book3

id  name
1   Pub1
2   Pub2
3   Pub3

book_id publisher_id    published_date
1         1             2021-06-06 20:12:30.7540000
1         2             2021-06-06 20:12:30.7540000
2         1             2021-06-06 20:12:30.7540000
2         2             2021-06-06 20:12:30.7540000
3         3             2021-06-06 20:12:30.7540000
```

**Queries:**

1. I see 3 objects which is BookPublisher which somehow matches outer layer of expected results, but 2nd array book2 object not available. i see only bookid, Why?
2. How to hide all the id's and nested mappings, i only need Book->Set of Publishers like expected results?
3. Am i querying right repository class which is BookPublisherRepository?

Highly appreciated your help on this issue investigation and the proposed solution in advance.

Comment: You have @Data annotation?

Comment: @K.Nicholas Yes. I do only mentioned Data in BookPublisherId class. But if i put Data in All the classes it results in circular and application queries ( book_publisher bookpublis0_ inner join Publisher publisher1_ on bookpublis0_.publisher_id=publisher1_.id where bookpublis0_.book_id=? ) this unlimited time. Is that something wrong in placing Data annotation?